# How to convert 8 bits Grayscale image to NV12 (limited range) color space using IPP

Tags: c, grayscale, yuv, intel-ipp, nv12-nv21

Video encoders like Intel® Media SDK do not accept 8 bits Grayscale image as input format.
8 bits [Grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) format applies one byte per pixel in range [0, 255].

8 bits YUV format in the context of the question applies [YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) (BT.601 or BT.709).
Although there is a full range YUV standard, the commonly used format is "limited range" YUV, where range of Y is [16, 235] and range of U,V is [16, 240].

[NV12 format](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV12) is the common input format in this case.
NV12 format is YUV 4:2:0 format ordered in memory with a Y plane first, followed by packed chroma samples in interleaved UV plane:
`YYYYYY`
`YYYYYY`
`UVUVUV`

[image]

The Grayscale image will be referred as "I plane":
`IIIIII`
`IIIIII`

[image]

Setting the UV plane is simple: Set all U,V elements to 128 value.

But what about the Y plane?

In case of full range YUV, we can simply put "I plane" as Y plane (i.e Y = I).

In case of "limited" YUV format, a transformation is required:
Setting R=G=B in the conversion formula results: **Y = round(I*0.859 + 16).**

**What is the efficient way to do the above conversion using [IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp)?**

Comment: I would use the full Y range from 0..255 with no conversion, since there's strong precedent for this practice even if it goes against the original definition of luma.

Comment: Are you sure Media SDK doesn't accept gray8? What about `MFX_CHROMAFORMAT_MONOCHROME` ?

Comment: @apalopohapa No, I am not sure... As I recall when I used H.264 video encoder, the only suppored format (without using VPP color space conversion) was NV12.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an answer to my own question.
I hope to see a better answer...

I found a solution using two IPP functions:

- [ippsMulC_8u_Sfs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/502099) - Multiplies each element of a vector by a constant value.
- [ippsAddC_8u_ISfs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/502095) - Adds a constant value to each element of a vector.

I selected functions that uses fixed point math, for better performance.

- Fixed point implementation of `0.859` scaling is performed by expanding, scaling and shifting. Example: `b = (a*scale + (1<<7)) >> 8;` [When `scale` = `(0.859)*2^8`].
  `val` parameter to `ippsMulC_8u_Sfs` set to `round(0.859*2^8)` = `220`.
  `scaleFactor` parameter to `ippsMulC_8u_Sfs` set to `8` (divide the scaled result by `2^8`).

Code sample:

```
void GrayscaleToNV12(const unsigned char I[],
                     int image_width,
                     int image_height,
                     unsigned char J[])
{
    IppStatus ipp_status;
    const int image_size = image_width*image_height;

    unsigned char *UV = &J[image_size]; //In NV12 format, UV plane starts below Y.

    const Ipp8u expanded_scaling = (Ipp8u)(0.859 * 256.0 + 0.5);

    //J[x] = (expanded_scaling * I[x] + 128u) >> 8u;
    ipp_status = ippsMulC_8u_Sfs(I,                 //const Ipp8u* pSrc,
                                 expanded_scaling,  //Ipp8u val,
                                 J,                 //Ipp8u* pDst,
                                 image_size,        //int len,
                                 8);                //int scaleFactor);

    //Check ipp_status, and handle errors...

    //J[x] += 16;
    //ippsAddC_8u_ISfs is deprecated, I used it to keep the code simple.
    ipp_status = ippsAddC_8u_ISfs(16,           //Ipp8u val, 
                                  J,            //Ipp8u* pSrcDst, 
                                  image_size,   //int len, 
                                  0);           //int scaleFactor);

    //Check ipp_status, and handle errors...

    //2. Fill all UV plane with 128 value - "gray color".
    memset(UV, 128, image_width*image_height/2);
}
```

---

*Out of topic note:*
There is a way to mark a video stream as "full range" (where `Y` range is [0, 255] instead of [`16`, `235`], and `U`,`V` range is also [0, 255]).
Using the "full range" standard allows placing `I` in place of `Y` (i.e **Y = I**).

Marking the stream as "full range" using Intel Media SDK, is possible (but not well documented).
Marking H.264 stream as "full range" requires to add pointer to `mfxExtBuffer **ExtParam` list (in structure `mfxVideoParam`):
A pointer to structure of type `mfxExtVideoSignalInfo` should be added with the following values:

```
typedef struct {
    mfxExtBuffer Header; //MFX_EXTBUFF_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO and sizeof(mfxExtVideoSignalInfo)
    mfxU16 VideoFormat; //Most likely 5 ("Unspecified video format")
    mfxU16 VideoFullRange; //1 (video_full_range_flag is equal to 1)
    mfxU16 ColourDescriptionPresent; //0 (description_present_flag equal to 0)
    mfxU16 ColourPrimaries; //0 (no affect when ColourDescriptionPresent = 0)
    mfxU16 TransferCharacteristics; //0 (no affect when ColourDescriptionPresent = 0)
    mfxU16 MatrixCoefficients; //0 (no affect when ColourDescriptionPresent = 0)
} mfxExtVideoSignalInfo;
```

`VideoFullRange = 1` is the only relevant parameter of setting "full range" video, but we must fill the entire structure.